# Python-Slenium-Get value from clipboard when click button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, clipboard, pyperclip

Here is a button on the page which when I clicked copies, a value was set to the clipboard.
Ex: button click to save wallet address.

It's simple when use single case (with **tk** or **pyperclip**.....), but when multi-threading, clipboard so messing.

I have no ideal for this case!

Thank for your time!

Ex with metamask wallet:
[Metamask Wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FTu7.png)

#with pyperclip:

import pyperclip

value=pyperclip.paste()

*Solved
It called tooltips elements, just move to element and get value*

Comment: Post the URL and the code you've tried.

Comment: @AbiSaran I have no ideal for my case, bro. I tried to copy my blockchain address from dApp, like metamask. You can find picture 'Metamask Wallet' above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It was called 'Tooltips' elements, just move to element, and get value of element!